# Blackberry return to the previus position in ListField

Tags: blackberry, cursor-position, listfield

In my application I'm using a list.
This list can be updated by a refresh list button which is retriving more data from serever.
When user pressing the refresh button, my application seves the last selected item into a memeber field -

```
lastPosition = listField.getSelectedIndex();
```

After updating the list, my application uses -

```
listField.setSelectedIndex(lastPosition);
```

for setting the last position.
But nothing happen.

How can i "move" the list's cursor to point on the lastPosition?
Thanks,
Eyal.

```
                listField.setKeyword("");
            listField.v = userVector;               
            listField.updateList(); 
            listField.getResultList();
            listField.setSelectedIndex(lastPosition);
            listField.setFocus();
            Manager manager = listField.getManager();
            int rowHeight = listField.getRowHeight();
            manager.setVerticalScroll(lastPosition * rowHeight);
            listField.invalidate();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to guess what is wrong without seeing the code, however the first thing that comes to mind is probably you don't set focus on the list right after you restore the position? If you don't, then try it:

```
listField.setSelectedIndex(lastPosition);
listField.setFocus();
```

Comment: Now. the cursor "jumps" back to the first item in the ListField.

Comment: how about setting focus to the listfield at first, then setting the index?

Comment: It seems like setSelectedIndex has no effect.

Comment: @eyal: Does the underlying collection change its size on "refresh" action? If yes, do you call `ListField.setSize(newSize)` on it (API says: `Invoke this method to reset the number of items in this field, and select the first item in the list.`)? Are you sure the `lastPosition` is a non-zero value when you call `listField.setSelectedIndex(lastPosition)`?

Comment: Thanks. after adding ListField.setSize(newSize) it start working.